# How to send two request simultaneously and get response one by one in C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to fetch two types of data which require to send two requests simultaneously and then store responses in the list in a way that first it should add the first response and then the second response.

For Example, I need to first show users and then teams so I am sending the corresponding requests first to fetch people and second to fetch teams. So how to make sure that first request's response should come first?

Comment: Can you provide code you have already tried? Have you used `await` to synchronise?

Answer (score 0):

You have not really provided enough details... but to guess at an answer.
You can

> send two requests simultaneously

By firing two async methods without awaiting them - this will go and 'get' your responses.
You then can await the tasks in the order you want to add them to the list:

```
public IEumerable<Response> GetResponses {
    // This will 'kick-off' both methods, but not actually get their results
    var userResponseTask = GetUserResponses();
    var groupResponseTask = GetGroupResponses();

    // Now you can pull the results in the order you like
    var responses = new List<Response>();
    responses.AddRange(await userResponseTask);
    responses.AddRange(await groupResponseTask);
    return responses;
}
```

Where GetUserResponses and GetGroupResponses are async methods like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Response>> GetUserResponses(){
    // However you get them
    return await SomeCallToWebServiceOrDatabaseEtc();
}
```

Comment: That's what I am doing but still some time second request's response comes earlier than first one.

Comment: @SauravKumar That doesn't sound right - show us your current code you must have done something different

Answer (score -1):

You could add your Requests to a List and then iterate over them.

```
List<Requests> requestList = new List<Request>();
List<Response> responseList = new List<Response>();
requestList.Add(requestObjectForUsers);
requestList.Add(requestObjectForTeams);
foreach(var request in requestList){
    responseList.Add( request.Send() );
}
```

This way the requests will be send one after another in a procedural way. If your request for the teams has a dependency to the response of the users then you should declare a variable where you put the user-Response and initialize it with null.

```
Response userResponse = null
foreach(var request in requestList){
    if(userResponse == null){
        // do the user request
    } else {
        // do the teams request
    }
}
```